# Cannot deactivate Office on a computer

Tags: office365

I have Office365 and am running office on 5 computers.  I am trying to deactivate the first computer listed, but when I click on the "Deactivate" button for that computer, nothing happens.  If I click on the "Deactivate" button for other computers, it appears to work and it pulls up the screen asking for confirmation.

How can I deactivate the first computer?  (I no longer own or have access to that computer)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP says "I no longer own or have access to that computer", so they won't be able to test or confirm anything we suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The availability of this  option in the Office 365 portal is so you can de-activate the licenses without having to have the system available.

When you use this feature it does not "reach" out to the machine in any way.  The next time someone on that machine logs on after it's deactivated they receive a message that it is not licensed and they need to logon with an account that has a valid license.

@b52703 you have indicated it's working for other entries but this one. If you have admin access to the Office 365 subscription (If you do not have your Admin try):

1. Logon  https://portal.office.com/Admin/Default.aspx#ActiveUsersPage
2. Select your user account
3. in detail pane you will find a section for "Office Installation" click "edit"
4. Have them try and de-activate the license from here.

I've looked a the user and license objects in powershell but don't see a method there to manage activation.  So if the above doesn't work - your next step is put in a support ticket and have Microsoft support remove it forcefully.